# SQLite and MySQL for websites

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, sqlite

I'm creating a service that allows people to purchase configurable websites. But I'm trying to make it as easy as possible for them to save the configuration settings.

Should I stick with MySQL or should I try SQLite? Is SQLite secure if the file is in the web root directory? I'm using PHP to access the database.

Comment: "*SQLite secure if the file is in the web root directory?*" it should be stored below the web root

Comment: @THeK:From my point of view, what you should be asking is: Can I use MySQL as part of my commercial product WITHOUT buying a license?. (I don't think you have one, right?)
Because your question does not make sense in other respect. It is like comparing apples and oranges

Comment: @user384706 MySQL is free and it's license allows you to sell products that us MySQL even if it is a for-profit application. I am not physically selling MySQL, instead asking the "client" to have it in order to use the application.

Comment: @THeK:Not sure about this.http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html

Comment: @user384706 From what I've read, I don't need a license because I'm not physically bundling MySQL, modified or not with my application. "In a third example, I make commercial software, which needs to have MySQL installed. My customers can use my commercial software, for which they do need to buy a license, in combination with the MySQL database engine, for which they don't need to pay. Because the MySQL engine is not embedded in my commercial software and I don't redistribute MySQL together with my software, I don't need a commercial license for MySQL and neither do my customers."

Comment: Quoted from http://blog.economy-x-talk.com/mysql-licenses-the-dos-and-donts-of-open-sour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I stick with MySQL or should I try SQLite?

Yes, unless you know a better 3rd one.

> Is SQLite secure if the file is in the web root directory? I'm

No file/program/system/computer is secure as long as people (hackers) have intelligence and we don't invent AI.

Comment: Do you really assume that the AI we invent will be secure?

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you, I'll probably give users the option. Can't believed I lost 5 points for asking a completely valid question though. I guess I caught this site in the middle of a mood swing.

Comment: @THeK thanks for the accept. I feel sorry of you but you probably misunderstood what kind of questions this site is for. Your question may be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com, as it is a site for conceptual questions.

Comment: @THeK:I will give you a +1 since no-one of the downvoters left a comment

Answer (score 0):

> Should I stick with MySQL or should I try SQLite? Is SQLite secure if
>   the file is in the web root directory?

They meet different requirements. MySQL is an SQL server engine (I assume you are not talking about the embedded version) while SQLIite is a file database.
SQLite for a small app with small data could give you a performance advantage.

> Is SQLite secure if the file is in the web root directory?

It is, as long as only your web application and *specific user accounts (perhaps only root besides the account of your web application)* have read/write access to that directory

Comment: To clarify, the SQLite file **should not** be downloadable. Always test that this is the case. Ideally it should not be in the web root, but another path a level above it.